# Toshiba laptop Windows 7

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I did a factory reset on my Toshiba laptop. I didn't realize it would wipe out all my existing files. Is there any way to recover the files that were on there before I reset it?

Comment: [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/q/241817)

Answer (score 2):

Factory reset does a reset to factopry state. As in, the state is was when you bought it and booted for the first time. That state has no personal data.

probably obvious in hindsight but painful for you.

It leaves you with these options:

- Restore from your backups. (You hopefully have backups for important files).
- Or **stop using the computer right now** and try to recover the old files from the drive. To prevent overwriting them do not use the disk at all. Remove the harddisk. Place in in another system and run recovery software.